# Errno 13 Permission denied with Django on a directory I don't want to use

Tags: python, django, apache, python-3.x, biopython

I have this error appearing in my Django app on my production server :

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.config'

I never asked to access to this unexisting file or directory in my code. The server is running in a different directory defined in my httpd.conf and I haven't defined the use of any */var/www/* elements in my Django settings.

In my case I'm using the biopython library with Django :

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "my@email"

handle = Entrez.efetch("taxonomy", id="123, 1")
records = Entrez.parse(handle)
```

This code is working in a python console on the server. But the instruction `Entrez.parse(handle)` return the error in a Django environment.

<strike>I haven't seen any instruction asking to write or open anything in the source code of the function so it seems to be a problem with Django?</strike>

Is it a configuration problem? A background Django function trying to access to a file when I call a specific function?

My configuration :

- Python 3.3
- Django 1.8
- Biopython 1.67

Comment: What does the full error point to? Who is trying to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In facts, `Entrez.parse` is calling the **DataHandler** objects. This objects try to write in the user directory with something like :

```
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
directory = os.path.join(home, '.config', 'biopython')
local_xsd_dir = os.path.join(directory, 'Bio', 'Entrez', 'XSDs')
os.makedirs(local_xsd_dir)
```

Because biopython user is the httpd user, the home directory is **/var/www/**.

The solution is here to allow *apache* to write into */var/www* or to move it to a different place.

Comment: Good answer, +1. I just looked at the source, and there is no way to override this behavior externally - i.e., you can't just run `from Bio.Entrez.Parser import DataHandler; DataHandler.local_storage_dir = "/tmp/biopython"` or something similar. I think I'll file a bug.

Comment: Check out and/or track [this issue](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/918) on Github if you're interested.

Comment: What do you mean with move it to a different place?

Answer (score 1):

Restart the server or restart the service of django.
That is important, because the services in the background have to know the new location of the configuration.

I guess it works on python, because the library is loading the actual settings and the background service is using the old one.

Hope I could help