# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/var/www/.config' - biopython

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, biopython

I have tried everything out there to try and get rid of this error including this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797372/django-errno-13-permission-denied-var-www-media-animals-user-uploads) post

Tried setting media root as mentioned elsewhere.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147935/errno-13-permission-denied-with-django-on-a-directory-i-dont-want-to-use) seems to have outlined the problem but no solution was given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA :)

```
     [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.config' 
        Request Method: POST
        -Django Version:    1.11.3 Exception Type:  PermissionError Exception Value:     
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.config' Exception 
        Location:   /home/--/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/os.py in
           makedirs, line 241 Python
           Executable:  /home/--/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/python 
        Python Version: 3.5.2 Python Path:   ['/home/--/myproject', 
           '/home/--/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python35.zip', 
           '/home/--/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5', 
           '/home/--/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
           '/home/--/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 
           '/usr/lib/python3.5',  '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
           '/home/--/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages'] Server
           time:    Sat, 12 Aug 2017 12:08:02 +0000
```

Error details from the server. Seems to be emanating from biopython trying to write to var/www/ folder

```
            raise exception ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
__module__  
'Bio.Entrez.Parser'
__qualname__    
'DataHandler'
local_dtd_dir   
'/var/www/.config/biopython/Bio/Entrez/DTDs'
local_xsd_dir   
'/var/www/.config/biopython/Bio/Entrez/XSDs'
/home/---/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py in DataHandler
        os.makedirs(local_dtd_dir)  # use exist_ok=True on Python >= 3.2 ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
__module__  
'Bio.Entrez.Parser'
__qualname__    
'DataHandler'
local_dtd_dir   
'/var/www/.config/biopython/Bio/Entrez/DTDs'
local_xsd_dir   
'/var/www/.config/biopython/Bio/Entrez/XSDs'
/home/---/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/os.py in makedirs
            makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
exist_ok    
False
head    
'/var/www/.config/biopython/Bio/Entrez'
mode    
511
name    
'/var/www/.config/biopython/Bio/Entrez/DTDs'
tail    
'DTDs'
/home/---/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/os.py in makedirs
            makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
exist_ok    
False
head    
'/var/www/.config/biopython/Bio'
mode    
511
name    
'/var/www/.config/biopython/Bio/Entrez'
tail    
'Entrez'
/home/---/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/os.py in makedirs
            makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
exist_ok    
False
head    
'/var/www/.config/biopython'
mode    
511
name    
'/var/www/.config/biopython/Bio'
tail    
'Bio'
/home/---/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/os.py in makedirs
            makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
exist_ok    
False
head    
'/var/www/.config'
mode    
511
name    
'/var/www/.config/biopython'
tail    
'biopython'
/home/---/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/os.py in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
exist_ok    
False
head    
'/var/www'
mode    
511
name    
'/var/www/.config'
tail    
'.config'
```

This is how wsgi config looks

```
Alias /static /home/usr/myproject/static
<Directory /home/usr/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/usr/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/usr/myproject python-home=/home/usr/myproject/myprojectenv
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/usr/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Comment: run your server as root

Comment: You cannot run code under mod_wsgi as root and running as root is a bad idea because if someone breaks into your application code, they are then root on your system. Trying overriding ``HOME`` environment variable to be a directory which is writable as the user Apache run as. Better still, ensure you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode and run the daemon process as distinct user account you create just to run your application.

Comment: I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797372/django-errno-13-permission-denied-var-www-media-animals-user-uploads

The GOOD solution would be:

codeblock>sudo groupadd varwwwusers
sudo adduser www-data varwwwusers
sudo chgrp -R varwwwusers /var/www/
sudo chmod -R 760 /var/www/

Wouldn't that open up the directory for apache?

Comment: I solved it by changing the ownership sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
Wondering what are the downsides, if any? @GrahamDumpleton, could you please comment? Thank you!